# Error : retrieved hash chain is invalid

Tags: ethereum

Whenever I attempt to run `geth` on the command line, it seems to have trouble syncing with the blockchain. I am getting these warnings continuously (this is run on testnet).

```
geth --testnet --rpc --rpcaddr "localhost" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,staker,net,txpool,shh " --rpcport 8545
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just exited my command prompt, and restarted the geth upgradedb process and it worked.

Another solution is set the current head of the local chain to a few blocks back with [debug.setHead command](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#debug_sethead). That rewind the chain back to the faulty snapshot block (epoch transaction), for all the signer nodes.

Like:

```
debug.setHead("0x124F80") // (1200000 th block)
```

From @karalabe's answer on the closed [issue](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/17849#issuecomment-428254931):

> There was a bug in one Geth release (v1.8.14/v1.8.15) that violated
>   the Clique consensus spec, causing some signers to create blocks when
>   they weren't allowed to (epoch transition). All previous and
>   subsequent version of Geth (apart from the faulty one) correctly
>   rejected those blocks, hence why you couldn't sync a new node to your
>   already mined chain.
>
> A node however does not re-validate blocks when you update it, so even
>   though you updated your signers, they were oblivious to the fact that
>   a faulty block was already in their chain. When you rewound the chain,
>   the signers had to re-mine the faulty segment, correcting the issue.
>
> This should most definitely not happen again, as long as you don't use
>   the faulty version of Geth. Any version equal or above to v1.8.16
>   should work just fine.